# I would like to use the value rendered in Node.js for Google Chart

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to use the value rendered in Node.js for Google Chart.

However, I can not successfully pass variables rendered on the server side to javascript on the client side.

I am using Node.js, Express and Pug.
Here is the code.

HTML(index.pug)

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js')

#chart_div
```

I used the "tests" variable in javascript as follows, but it did not go well

javascript

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

      for(var test of tests)
      {
         data.addRows([test]);
      }

      var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Popularity'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

Node.js

```
var tests = [[0, 0],[1, 10],[2, 23],[3, 17],[4, 18]];
res.render('index', {
    tests: tests
});
```

How can I pass "tests" variables to javascript on the client side?

Comment: You will want to look into something like `express` framework to send out the results.. You can then use an Ajax call from the client side to grab the data.

Comment: You can write the JS in a script tag in the index.pug that way you will have access to the tests object. if you don't want to make an AJAX request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a server side Javascript variable be defined in your page, you have to insert PUG syntax that renders that Javascript variable definition into your page.  For your `tests` variable, you would add something like this to your template:

```
script.
    var tests = #{tests};
```

And, change what you pass into the template to this:

```
res.render('index', {
    tests: JSON.stringify(tests)
});
```

Then, when the page is rendered, it will show up as:

```
<script>
    var tests = [[0, 0],[1, 10],[2, 23],[3, 17],[4, 18]];
</script>
```

And your variable will be defined in your page.

You also don't have to define the variable separately, you would just put `#{tests}` right into the middle of your Javascript where you wanted to use that value and have the array just inserted right there where it is needed.  It will work either way.

---

P.S. You should never iterate an array with `for/in` because that iterates all properties of the object, not just array entries which will work sometimes, but not necessarily always (the could include other properties of the object).  In ES5, use a traditional `for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` loop or use `.forEach()`.  In ES6, use `for/of`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Succeeded with this method!